# Is it possible for InstallShield 2012 to include a custom language file that isn't in <ISProductDIR>

Tags: installshield, installshield-2012

It's [very straightforward](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q106687) to add languages to an installshield project. My goal is to 
make a modified English `(0x0409.ini)` with some of the strings modified, such as

[image: Strings I want to modify]

However I have a team of people that would have to copy these files to a directory much like `C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2012Spring\Support` and`C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2012Spring\redist\`.  This is even worse with the 10+ machines in the build farm that could potentially need this file.  It's a non-starter. It's hacky to have modify the install of a tool to get it to use an unsupported language.

Is it possible to check the language file to SCM and have it reside in a subfolder of `<ISProjectDir>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe so. I think you'd have to set up a post-build step that would copy in a modified ini file.

You could set up one in installshield's UI but I don't know if that persists in a stand alone build.

Comment: In my shiny happy world the account running the build wouldn't have rights to hork the build machine (write to %PROGRAMFILES%).  It's frustrating that InstallShield is to software development as a 1984 Ford Escort is to the Indy 500.  It's not a tool for engineers.

Comment: This could be done without modifying your build system. Whatever custom ini file you want could be checked in alongside your ism file, and post-build it could copy it from there to your output location; thus automating the process without modifying the build system.